# Neo4j : Slow Selection Operation with Huge Data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to the nodes from the Graph randomly each time. the number of nodes is 24600968 in the database. The following query

```
MATCH (n:Employee)
WITH n AS emp,rand() AS ids ORDER BY ids LIMIT 10

MATCH (n:Company)
WITH emp, n AS com,rand() AS ids ORDER BY ids LIMIT 10
RETURN emp.guid,com.guid
```

is taking very long time. The time is

```
Returned 10 rows in 306863 ms.
```

How can I speed up this process.

Comment: What is the goal of your query? Would you like to sample the database by randomly selecting 10 employees?

Comment: I am developing a Graph Data Simulator. Where I have to pick nodes randomly and create the relationships.

Comment: I see. I do not have good idea for doing a "proper" sampling, but based on http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/sampling-a-neo4j-database/, you can try something like: `MATCH (n) WHERE rand() < 0.1 RETURN n LIMIT 10`. Unfortunately, this gives a skewed sample - the first nodes are much more likely to make it to the sample.

Comment: Skewness cannot generlize my requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. run 2 separate statements
2. try this

Lookup nodes by a random set of ids and check if they are an employee

```
MATCH (n) WITH count(*) as total
WITH [_ IN range(1,10000) | toInt(rand()*total)] as ids
MATCH (emp) WHERE id(emp) IN ids AND emp:Employee
RETURN emp LIMIT 10
```

Your query generates a list of 24M random values and sorts it (twice) while also pulling that many nodes from the graph into memory (not sure how much memory you have)

Comment: In the range, why the upper limit is 10000? Instead of total.