# Neo4j: Pattern Simulation In Graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to simulate the patterns in graph. My Graph contains 20 Million Persons and 4 Million Organization. Now I have to select nodes randomly and create the patterns like this:

- (n1:Person:Employee)-[:EMPLOYED_BY]->(m1:Organization:Seller)
- (n2:Person:BuyerContact)-[:EMPLOYED_BY]->(m2:Organization:Buyer)
- (n1)-[:P2P]-(n2)

Here, in organization m1& m2 there can have more than 1 employee may be sometimes over 100 in number. Means, we have to select some n number of people and create a EMPLOYED_BY relationship in the above pattern.

Since, picking random samples is very tedious task in Neo4j, the operation taking quit long time to pick nodes randomly. How can I speed up the pattern simulation.

Comment: Add cipher query please

Comment: I did not write the Query yet. I am failing at getting random samples effectively.

Comment: what happened with my answer to your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691687/neo4j-slow-selection-operation-with-huge-data

Comment: Since I am looping it approx 300 times, the process is slow.